# Writing Modim DeRabanan on a Mezuza klaf

Tags: halacha, safrus

I would like to write the full Modim DeRabanan on Klaf that was made for Mezuza, I dont know what condition was made on it, its just regular Klaf you buy for Mezuza from the Stam store.

is it ok to write it on that Klaf?

If so, how would I write the names in there? should I write full names? (and Lekadesh them?)
or would it better to write יי (yod yod) and אלוקינו.
and for אלוקינו, would א-ל be a name too?

I would like to know the correct way of doing so.

thank you.

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Comment: How could anyone here answer what the status of your klaf is?? We know less about it than you do!!!

Comment: Its true, but halacha states that a regular klaf is usually conditioned so that you can use it for whatever you want, just wanted to make sure. The reason for doing that is just for personal use, putting it in my siddur and such.

Comment: Halacha does not state that. Questions of metzius depend on metzius. There is no general rule. And please spare me the nonsense, that's not a reason to do this since we both know your siddur already has it printed inside.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Elazar and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!